# If $f(x) = x(1 - x^n)^{-1/n}$, how many function compositions does it take for $f(f(f(\cdots f(x_0)))) > 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

Fix an integer $n \geq 1$ and let $f(x) := x(1 - x^n)^{-1/n}$. Fix $x_0 \in (0, 1)$. Then there exists an $N$ (depending on $n$ and $x_0$) such that $f(f(f(\cdots f(x_0)))) > 1$ where the function composition occurred $N$ times. Is there a way to estimate the order of magnitude of $N$ depending on $n$ and $x_0$, like what does $N$ asymptotically look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$:

$$\underbrace{f(\cdots f}_{k}(x_0)\cdots) = x (1 - k x_0^n)^{(-1/n)}$$

So just set this function to $1$ and solve for $k$:

$$k = \lceil (-1 + (1/x_0)^n) (1/x_0)^{-n} x_0^{-n} \rceil$$

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$?

Comment: Maybe you should add a proof of why $f(\cdots f(x_0)\cdots) = x (1 - k x_0^n)^{(-1/n)}$. Also $k$ can be simplified to $k = \lceil -1 + (1/x_0)^n\rceil$

Comment: You can  prove $f^k(x)=x(1-kx^n)^{-\frac{1}{n}}$ by induction. Clearly, $f^1(x)=x(1-1\cdot x^n)^{-\frac{1}{n}}$. Assume the induction hypothesis holds, and by the definition of functional composition:
$$\begin{align*}f^{k+1}(x)&=\frac{f^k(x)}{\sqrt[n]{1-[f^k(x)]^n}}\\
&=\frac{x(1-kx^n)^{-\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt[n]{1-[x(1-kx^n)^{-\frac{1}{n}}]^n}}\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{(1-kx^n)(1-x^n(1-kx^n)^{-1})}}\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{(1-kx^n)[1-kx^n-x^n](1-kx^n)^{-1}}}\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{1-(k+1)x^n}}\\
&=x(1-(k+1)x^n)^{-\frac{1}{n}}\end{align*}$$
Proving the identity.